# Error: Looks like you have nested a 'NavigationContainer' inside another. Normally you need only one container at the root of the app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I followed the docs of React 5 for Drawer Navigation in react native but getting this error. Here is my Code

```
import React from 'react'
import {
    View,
    Button,
    Text,
} from 'react-native'

import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

import Screen1 from './DrawerScreens/Screen1';
import Screen2 from './DrawerScreens/Screen2';
import Screen3 from './DrawerScreens/Screen3';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function Navigations()
{
    return(
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
                <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Screen1} />
                <Drawer.Screen name="Settings" component={Screen2} />
                <Drawer.Screen name="Contacts" component={Screen3} />
            </Drawer.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}

export default Navigations;
```

I am new to react native, so don't know what to do

Comment: There is no problem here are you using NavigationContainer else where

Comment: @user12129132 yes I'm using it in another class too

Comment: can you add that file too that might be the reason you are getting this error

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You only need to declare one < NavigationContainer > in the top component, example:

```
function SecondComponent() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Feed" component={Feed} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Messages" component={Messages} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

function FirstComponent() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer> {/* this is the only NavigationContainer */}
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: where did you see it being declared more than once in the OP question?

Comment: I have the same problem and I anly have one `NavigationContainer` in the app

Answer (score 16):

pass `independent={true}` to both of the Navigation container .

```
<NavigationContainer independent={true}>
</NavigationContainer>
```

**But you will not be able to navigate between the screens of two separate navigation container**

If you want to navigate between them then you have to maintain single navigation container.

Comment: what was version of react-navigation?As this is not working in react navigation version 6

Answer (score 4):

If you have only one `NavigationContainer` in your app, please check if you're importing screens correctly.

In my case, I've mistakenly imported the entry route file which contains `NavigationContainer` itself.

This can happen if you're using same file names for entry route files (e.g. `Root.tsx` or `Main.tsx`) and let IDE import files automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You should have only one **`NavigationContainer`** in your whole application and it should be in the root level, which is the App class. So here you can see two different components, **`Navigation`** and **`App`**.

In **`Navigation`** component, **`Drawer Navigator`** helps to navigate different screens. Import this **`Navigation`** component in **`App`** component and wrap this with **`NavigationContainer`**.

```
// **** Navigation component ****
import React from 'react'; 
import {
    View,
    Button,
    Text, 
} from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';

import Screen1 from './DrawerScreens/Screen1'; 
import Screen2 from './DrawerScreens/Screen2'; 
import Screen3 from './DrawerScreens/Screen3';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function Navigation() {
    return (
        <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
            <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Screen1} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="Settings" component={Screen2} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="Contacts" component={Screen3} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
    ); 
}

export default Navigation;


// **** App component ****
import React from 'react'; 
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'; 
import {Navigation} from './Navigation';

function App() {   
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Navigation />
        </NavigationContainer>   
    ); 
}

export default App;
```

I faced similar type of error while using Stack Navigator and this approach works for me.

Comment: So Mr. Kabir it doesn't matter how many screens I have I need to declare all of them inside App.js?

Comment: Here Navigation component holds all the screens such as Home, Settings and Contacts which is wrapped by NavigationContainer in App component. So we have to put the individual screens in a component altogether in this case, the Navigation component.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have used BOTTOM NAVIGATION so it has that `<NavigationContainer>`
just removing `<NavigationContainer>` in BOTTOM NAVIGATION and only keeping it between `<Stack.Navigator>` resolved my problem

I think this will helpful for someone ✌

Answer (score 0):

If you have this issue in Expo 49, you can use Expo Routing instead of React-Navigation: https://docs.expo.dev/routing/introduction/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have created your app with `npx create-expo-app@latest --with-router`, in this case a default navigation container is added and it causes the issue when adding NavigationContainer