# react native navigation nested screen

Tags: react-native, navigation

i have screen with 2 tabs

```
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Main" component={Main}/>
        <Tab.Screen name="Chat" component={Chat}/>
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

Screen `Chat` very simple and it works :

```
const Chat = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Chat</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
export default Chat;
```

But in first screen `Main` i have nested screen `Map`

```
const Main = () => {
  return (
      <Map/>
  );
};

export default Main;
```

Tell me pls how nested screens works, because i have an error :

```
Error: Looks like you have nested a 'NavigationContainer' inside another. Normally you need only one container at the root of the app
```

Component `Map`:

```
export const Map = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE} // remove if not using Google Maps
        style={styles.map}
        region={{
          latitude: 37.78825,
          longitude: -122.4324,
          latitudeDelta: 0.015,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
        }}
      >
        <Marker
          title="title"
          description='descr'
          coordinate={{
            latitude: 37.78825,
            longitude: -122.4324,
          }}>
          <View style={{backgroundColor: "red", padding: 10}}>
            <Text>SF</Text>
          </View>
        </Marker>
      </MapView>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  },
});
```

Comment: What's in Map component ? Seems like you have a NavigationContainer inside

Comment: @BloodyMonkey updated a body of question with Map component. Its just google maps tamplate

Comment: Okay it's not the problem, make sure you don't have a second NavigationContainer, maybe at root. Try to search in whole project folder (ctrl+maj+f in VSCode)

Comment: @BloodyMonkey no :-) i have not another NavigationContainer, just at one place

Comment: Look again, it's the only possibility. Maybe it can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61677422/error-looks-like-you-have-nested-a-navigationcontainer-inside-another-normal

Comment: @BloodyMonkey its very strange, i tested at another nested component and it works, but maps- does not

Comment: @BloodyMonkey done! problem was in wrong import MapView!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was in wrong import MapView!